# Calculate average from data only stored in MySQL on change

Tags: mysql, timestamp, average, intervals

We have a database where we only store data values and timestamp (as a row in MySQL) **when the data value changes.** There are therefore no fixed interval between the timestamps in the database. The table looks something like this:

```
MySQLTimestamp    Data
2014-10-01 18:01  1
2014-10-03 16:13  2
2014-10-07 15:45  1
2014-10-09 10:08  3
```

**THE PROBLEM:** We want to calculate the average **over time** assuming that the data value continues to be i.e. 2 until the value changes on the next row in the database.

A simple AVG won't do the trick because it will only calculate the average between the number of rows. This would not take in to count that a value can continue to be the same value for a long period of time before the next row states a change in data value.

Would really appreciate your help!

Comment: What do you mean with `over time`? How would the desired result look like?

Comment: With "over time" I mean that I need the avarage between two dates. Sorry that I was a bit unclear about that. The desired function should look something like this: GetLogAvg($FromDate, $ToDate) { ..... return Avg }. I do want to to it all in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Self join and calculate the duration of date or time as weight to `Data`.

```
select 
    sum(data*duration_of_date)/sum(duration_of_date) as avg_over_date,
    sum(data*duration_of_hour)/sum(duration_of_hour) as avg_over_hour,
    sum(data*duration_of_sec)/sum(duration_of_sec) as avg_over_sec
from (
    select 
        t1.MySQLTimestamp,
        t1.data,
        min(case when t1.MySQLTimestamp<t2.MySQLTimestamp 
                 then t2.MySQLTimestamp else null end) as next_tm,
        datediff( 
            min(case when t1.MySQLTimestamp<t2.MySQLTimestamp 
                     then t2.MySQLTimestamp else null end) , 
            t1.MySQLTimestamp) as duration_of_date,
        TIME_TO_SEC(timediff( 
            min(case when t1.MySQLTimestamp<t2.MySQLTimestamp 
                     then t2.MySQLTimestamp else null end) , 
            t1.MySQLTimestamp))/60/60 as duration_of_hour,
        TIME_TO_SEC(timediff( 
            min(case when t1.MySQLTimestamp<t2.MySQLTimestamp 
                     then t2.MySQLTimestamp else null end) , 
            t1.MySQLTimestamp)) as duration_of_sec
    from 
        your_table t1
    cross join 
        your_table t2
    group by 
        t1.MySQLTimestamp, 
        t1.data
    ) as t
```

Use `datediff` to calculate days interval as weight. If you want hours or minutes as interval, you could use `timediff` and transfer the result to hours, minutes or seconds.

Here is the [sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd798/11) and the results:

```
AVG_OVER_DATE   AVG_OVER_HOUR   AVG_OVER_SEC
          1.5         1.51887         1.5189
```

Another version by left join:

```
select 
    sum(data*duration_of_date)/sum(duration_of_date) as avg_over_date,
    sum(data*duration_of_hour)/sum(duration_of_hour) as avg_over_hour,
    sum(data*duration_of_sec)/sum(duration_of_sec) as avg_over_sec
from (
    select 
        t1.MySQLTimestamp,
        t1.data,
        min(t2.MySQLTimestamp) as next_tm,
        datediff(min(t2.MySQLTimestamp), t1.MySQLTimestamp) as duration_of_date,
        TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(min(t2.MySQLTimestamp), t1.MySQLTimestamp))/60/60 as duration_of_hour,
        TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(min(t2.MySQLTimestamp), t1.MySQLTimestamp)) as duration_of_sec
    from 
        your_table t1
    left join 
        your_table t2
    on 
        t1.MySQLTimestamp<t2.MySQLTimestamp
    group by 
        t1.MySQLTimestamp, 
        t1.data
    ) as t
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks man! I will give this a go this weekend, i'll let you know!